# Drupal 7 Select query with If condition mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, drupal, drupal-7

```
function tablesort_example_page() {
//$date2=date('m-d-Y', strtotime('t.added_date'));
// if('t.status'==1){
// $status='Active';
// }else{
// $status='Inactive';
// }
  // We are going to output the results in a table with a nice header.
  $header = array(
    // The header gives the table the information it needs in order to make
    // the query calls for ordering. TableSort uses the field information
    // to know what database column to sort by.
    array('data' => t('S No'), 'field' => 't.id'),
    array('data' => t('Country Name'), 'field' => 't.country_name'),
    array('data' => t('Status'), 'field' => 't.status'),
    array('data' => t('Added Date'), 'field' => 't.added_date'),
    array('data' => t('Action'), 'field' => 't.id',),
    array('data' => t('Action'), '',),
  );

  // Using the TableSort Extender is what tells the the query object that we
  // are sorting.
  $limit = 10;


  $query = db_select('countries', 't')->extend('TableSort')->extend('PagerDefault')->limit($limit)->orderby('id', ASC);
  $query->fields('t');

  // Don't forget to tell the query object how to find the header information.
  $result = $query
      ->orderByHeader($header)
      ->execute(); 
if('$row->status'==0){
$status='Active';
} else {
$status='Inactive';
}
  $rows = array();
  $i=1;
  foreach ($result as $row) {
//print_r($row);


    // Normally we would add some nice formatting to our rows
    // but for our purpose we are simply going to add our row
    // to the array.
    $rows[] = array(
    $row->id,
    $row->country_name,
    $status, ----> **
```

> here i need to execute the If condition for `$status`

```
    //$row->added_date,
    date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->added_date)),
    l('edit', 'mypages/countries/'. $row->id),
    l('delete', 'mypages/delete/'. $row->country_name)
    );
    $i++;
  }
```

As per my database table the below are my table fields.

(`id`, `country_name`, `status`, `added_date`)

In Status there will be `0` or `1` 
 now my Question is i need to display status

```
if  0 - Inactive
    1 - Active
```

Comment: You can use views to achieve this - Check this link https://www.drupal.org/project/views

Comment: i am using custom module

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest using a PHP ternary operator to test the value in the status field and output a string description based on that value.

```
$rows[] = array(
  $row->id,
  $row->country_name,
  ($row->status == 0) ? 'Inactive' : 'Active',
  date('d-m-Y H:i:s', strtotime($row->added_date)),
  l('edit', 'mypages/countries/'. $row->id),
  l('delete', 'mypages/delete/'. $row->country_name)
);
```

Comment: But its showing inactive...even if we have active also

Comment: Sorry, my bad - I overlooked correcting the $status variable to $row->status.  Your previous code was comparing a string to an integer ('$row->status' == 0) which will always return false.

See my edited answer above which has the corrected variable.

Comment: can you check with below question as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35649414/how-to-make-drupal-7-editable-field-in-table-for-admin-only